# gulp-autoprefixer error on comment in scss

Tags: gulp, comments, autoprefixer

Give an error when i comment something in my scss. Without autoprefixer it works normally.
I try gulp-autoprefixer v.9.0.0 it needs EMS. I acualy dont now how to do this. And with v.7.x.x or v.8.x.x
it gives this error. How to fix this?

[[[[no](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oHZZS.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/veJAK.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y3hKA.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/71Fe0.png)

Comment: Please don't post images of code. Instead, copy and paste the code into your question and use markdown to format it correctly.